# Ionic 4 Router Link and queryParams not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I have been trying different solution i found here. However, none of it works. I am able to produce the link with parameters but still not able to get it in another component. here is my code:

app-routing.module:

```
  { path: 'branch', loadChildren: './branch/branch.module#BranchPageModule' }
```

choosePage.html:

```
 <ion-col>
    <a class="flex" [routerLink]= "['/branch']" [queryParams]="{ id: '17'}" routerDirection="forward">
         <!-- something here -->
    </a>
  </ion-col>
```

branch.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-branchprofile',
  templateUrl: './branchprofile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./branchprofile.page.scss'],
})

export class BranchprofilePage implements OnInit {

  brand: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.id)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); 

        this.brand = params.id;
        console.log(this.brand); 
      });
    }
}
```

branch.page.html:

```
{{ brand }}
```

What could be missing?? Even in `console.log` have nothing

Comment: Have you tried without the filter function? I think possibly you need to receive the value from the subscribe function before you can do anything with it

Comment: Does the query params appear in the address bar correctly at least?

Comment: @chrismclarkeyes it does `http://localhost:8100/branch?id=17`, yes I have remove the filter, same result.

Comment: ok, good to know. Could you also add your branch.page.module.ts seeing as this is lazy loaded. There might be a clue in there somewhere also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply filter until after you have received data, and from the looks of it you don't need to apply at all as you can just access the params directly

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams

      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); 

        this.brand = params.id;
        console.log(this.brand); 
      });
    }
```

Otherwise you will need to make sure you have imported the routermodule into your child page component also. Here is a working blitz with code from above https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-routing-starter-lbevwv

Answer (score 1):

Updating... you can use `paramMap` as well:

```
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute){

     this.actRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
      if (params) {
        console.log('param => ', params['params']);
      }else{
        console.log('No Params...');
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: To read the parameter, you can use ```this.YourProperty = params.get('id');```